# Use object returned by Lua script

Tags: c#, lua, moonsharp

I have this lua script inside "Conversion.lua" file:

```
local conversion = {}

function conversion.mmToin( value )
    return value * 0.0393701
end

return conversion
```

I need to use the function `mmToin` in C# code, contained inside the object `conversion`.

If the function would not be inside the object i would have use the following code:

```
Script scp = new Script();
scp.DoFile(GlobalConst.PATH_TO_SCRIPT_FOLDER + "Conversion.lua");
double resultFm = scp.Call(scp.Globals["mmToin"], 1).ToObject<double>();
```

but i can't use the function if i put it inside an object; i've tried:

```
double resultFm = scp.Call(scp.Globals["conversion.mmToin"], 1).ToObject<double>();
```

but is not working.

How can i use `mmToin` function inside C# code?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to look up `mmToin` in the returned table, not in the global one.

Comment: Can you write the snippet that do that? I searched in the returned table `DynValue.Table` but the length is 0

Comment: I don't really know how to do it in C# unfortunately, I'm used to using C to interact with Lua. However the Lua internals should work the same, so the `DoFile` should leave a table on the stack (the returnvalue) which has a key `mmToin` with the value of the function.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"? What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: Well exception is fired with message `function is not a function and has no __call metamethod`. I suppose because function is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the returned value of your lua script as a DynValue object, then look for the desired function in the Table property.

```cs
DynValue dyn = scp.DoFile(GlobalConst.PATH_TO_SCRIPT_FOLDER + "Conversion.lua");
```

and you should be then able to call your function with

```cs
scp.Call(dyn.Table.Get("yourFunctionHere"), parameters).ToObject<double>();
```